# HyperV fails to run VMs that are connected to a virtual switch, but works for VMs that are not connected

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I am running Windows 10 20H2 on a HP EliteBook G4.

#### I have the following problem:

I cannot run VMs attached to a virtual switch.

- All VMs run successfully when not using a Virtual Switch ("not connected" under network adapter)
- When I assign a virtual switch (any type, any kind) to a VM, it hangs in starting at 10% and eventually fails with a timeout error. I tried both an empty VM not containing an OS (this should at least show the UEFI screen) and a VM containing an installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I expect that I can run VMs connected to virtual switches.

#### What have I tried?

- Disable Antivirus
- Network reset in Windows 10 (multiple times, e.g. netcfg -d)
- Uninstall Hyper-V, delete any superfluous networking interfaces and reinstall it
- Upgrade Windows 10 (it was at 1903 before that)
- Update ethernet driver with that from HP
- Delete ethernet driver and use the default
- Upgrade BIOS
- file system and system files checks

In total I already spent about 20h also involving people from IT on this problem researching and trying various commands, following various websites. It is a problem I have not found so far (or still missed?). I hope to find someone that had the exact same problem and can remember the solution.

#### What errors do I get?

I think these are the relevant ones:

- Hyper-V-Worker

  - Event ID 12006 with following message

    - 'Ubuntu20.04.1LTS' Synthetic Ethernet Port: Failed to finish reserving resources with Error 'This operation returned because the timeout period expired.' (0x800705B4). (Virtual machine ID XXXX-XXX-...)
  - Event ID 12030 with following message

    - 'Ubuntu20.04.1LTS' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID XXXX-XXX-...)
  - Event ID 12010 with following message for a "Generation 1" VM with a legacy network adapter

    - 'Emptyv1_net' Emulated Ethernet Port (Instance ID XXXX-XXX-...): Failed to Power on with Error 'Access is denied.' (0x80070005). (Virtual machine ID XXXX-XXX-...)
- Hyper-V-SynthNic

  - Event ID 12670 with following messages

    - 'Ubuntu20.04.1LTS' failed to allocate resources while connecting to a virtual network: This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (0x800705B4) (Virtual Machine ID XXXX-XXX-...). The Ethernet switch may not exist.
    - 'Ubuntu20.04.1LTS' failed to allocate resources while connecting to a virtual network: Access is denied. (0x80070005) (Virtual Machine ID XXXX-XXX-...). The Ethernet switch may not exist.

Comment: Are you using the default Virtual Switch? If yes, did you try creating and using a new one?

Comment: Hi, yes I created different kinds of switches, internal, external (with either the ethernet NIC or the wifi NIC), and private switches. I disabled all extensions (it said Microsoft NDIS Packet Capturing filter was not working properly). I unchecked some options in the settings of the VM. However, nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you done all of what [this article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-hyper-v-network-adapter-not-connected) lists?

Comment: I had not, but I could not fully do it as on this page because I am required to select a home network when I check that box. Anyway, I have tried various settings, some of which changed the Ip on my adapter to 192.168.137.1. It did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you changed manually any default setting in the VM network adapter properties manually?

Comment: Thanks, the network adapters have been recreated several times as I did network reset and removed those instances. The last time, before I installed Hyper-V I removed all network adapters so Hyper-V recreated the default switch from scratch. I am still wondering why it says "Access is denied." The error message is very unhelpful, I have no idea what access is meant and how it is denied. My user does have administrative rights on the PC. I also tried to create a local user with administrative rights, but that didn't help either. It's some other form of "access is denied".

Comment: This is unusual. General troubleshooting: In an elevated CMD run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Googling it seems ` netcfg -d` wipes all your network adapters, can't find official Microsoft documentation on it. That alone caused more issues for people trying to troubleshoot something else. I speculate maybe that is HOW this trouble started. Maybe it leaves residue of the old NIC's in the registry & now everything is gunked up. @harrymc advise is a good idea. If that doesn't fix I'd look at removing the Hyper-V role, restarting, then re-adding. If that doesn't fix you may have to reinstall Windows

Comment: @gregg: The poster already reinstalled Hyper-V. If my above advice doesn't help. I would counsel [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc: I ran those commands during Windows 10 1903 without any effect, then I upgraded to 20H2. I think the problem is somewhat deeper. If no fix turns out I will rather reinstall Windows 10 completely than spend more time with a half-hearted repair.
@gregg: `netcfg -d` did not result in much trouble. All adapters were removed and after doing a restart as prompted, Windows found and added them again. I also tried the `Network reset` option in the official Windows 10 settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade to Windows 20H2
did not help, it seems like you need to reinstall, unfortunately.

I suggest to backup your data and reinstall Windows from scratch, meaning
not as an upgrade. You will need to reinstall all your applications.

Reformatting the install partition is optional, and perhaps should only be used
if the simple installation failed to solve the problem.

Comment: I have one last option to try regarding drivers of checkpoint SSL, otherwise, yes I will have to do a reinstallation and either conclude that it then works or that there is some hardware defect.

Comment: The laptop has now been wiped with a fresh installation of Windows 10 20H2 and I can confirm that it works now, thus no hardware defect. It seems that the previous installation suffered from an unknown problem that could not be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, and good luck.